# jquery .html() problem with IE

Tags: jquery, html

```
<form name = "id_form">
     <input type = "hidden" name= "id_data" value = "'.$id.'">
     <input type = "button" value = "Request Price" id = "sess_s" >
</form>

$('#sess_s').click(function() {
    $.post('data.php',{id_value: id_form.id_data.value  },
       function(output) {
       $('#sess_feed_top').html(output).show();
    });

 });
```

As soon I click the button `#sess_s`, the data suppose to show disappears in IE. It works fine with other browsers. I think the problem with .html(output).
any solution? thanks

Comment: I'd remove the extra spaces from your HTML. That's bad practice to have them there.

Comment: more than likely something is not escaped well in the 'output' returned from data.php, can you post the html that works in other browsers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can rely on global variables for form fields.

```
var dataHolder = $('form[name=id_form] input[name=id_data]');

$('#sess_s').click(function() {
    $.post(
        'data.php',
         {id_value: dataHolder.val()},
         function(output) {
             $('#sess_feed_top').html(output).show();
         }
    );
});
```